# Enable Second typeit only after first is complete

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to include typing effect on my website. For that I was trying to use TypeIt, a JS Library for it. 
I am able to make it work but the problem is I want the second TypeIt instance to run only when the first is complete. 
As in their [Documentation](https://typeitjs.com/docs/) there is a method called `instance.isComplete`

Here is how I was trying it.

HTML

```
<p id="example1"></p>
<p id="example2"></p>
```

The JavaScript is

```
var instance =   new TypeIt('#example1', {
strings: ["FIRST TEXT"],
speed: 75,
autoStart: true
});


while(1)
{
  if(instance.isComplete)
   {
     new TypeIt('#example2', {
     strings: ["TEXT TO APPEAR AFTER FIRST IS COMPLETE"],
     speed: 75,
     autoStart: true
   });
    break;
   }
}
```

I was trying to use a loop that will break once the instance is complete but the problem is I am stuck in an Infinite Loop and page won't load

Comment: does TypeIt have a hook that's triggered when it completes? (then you can drop a callback function inside of that instead of using a loop)

Comment: I would look in the documentation for things called "events" or "callback methods". Using a while loop like that is a Bad Idea.

Comment: instance.isComplete returns true as soon as it finishes typing the first instance @Doug

Comment: I would try doing that @MikeMcCaughan

Comment: It's [right here](https://typeitjs.com/docs/#available-methods).  You can assign a method to `afterComplete` when you set the options.

Comment: Found it thanks @JosephMarikle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can place your second call in the `afterComplete` property when you declare the options for the first one; however, I feel like there's probably a better way to do this.  You might want to go over the documentation again.

```js
var instance =   new TypeIt('#example1', {
  strings: ["FIRST TEXT"],
  speed: 75,
  autoStart: true,
  afterComplete: function(instance){
    instance.destroy();
    new TypeIt('#example2', {
      strings: ["TEXT TO APPEAR AFTER FIRST IS COMPLETE"],
      speed: 75,
      autoStart: true
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typeit/5.10.1/typeit.min.js"></script>
<p id="example1"></p>
<p id="example2"></p>
```

## Edit:

Here is the effect I think you're going for:

```js
var instance =   new TypeIt('#example1', {
  speed: 75,
  autoStart: true
})
.type('FIRST TEXT')
.break()
.type('TEXT TO APPEAR AFTER FIRST IS COMPLETE');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typeit/5.10.1/typeit.min.js"></script>
<p id="example1"></p>
<p id="example2"></p>
```

The documentation site had a [demo codepen](https://codepen.io/alexmacarthur/pen/MOPQvp)

Comment: Thanks for the help. It is working now. I would go through the documentation again and try to find if there is a better way.

Comment: @Parth I think I've found a better approach.  See my edit to my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! @Joseph

Comment: But the second approach writes it in the save div/para. What if i want them in two different ids? @Joseph

Comment: @Parth If they're existing elements, then the first approach is probably what you need.  You can use HTML instead of plain text, but there are limitations.  I just tried it with paragraphs and it didn't place the cursor correctly.